# TaskId from Kafka Task

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to export some custom metrics from my own Kafka Connector.
I need to get more information on a SinkTask particularly the taskId of the SinkTask.
However I am unable to find any documentation or API reference on getting this taskID. Reading the source code doesn't throw any light too.
How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check Confluent documentation [`Monitoring Kafka Connect and Connectors: Sink task metrics`](https://docs.confluent.io/home/connect/monitoring.html#sink-task-metrics): you can get the taskId of the Sink Task from `task` attribute.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
SinkTask doesn't have an attribute by name `task` 
The link you mention is an overview of the documentation of the REST API and the various JMX exported metrics.
I am unable to see how to get `taskId` from `task` from there.

Comment: You can get `taskId` from MBean `MBean: kafka.connect:type=sink-task-metrics,connector=([-.w]+),task=([d]+)`: `task=([d]+)` attribute is `taskId`

Comment: How do you try to export metrics? Do you use `jmx_exporter` or something else?

Comment: Yes I am using `jmx_exporter` for exporting the metrics. Additionally this may sound as a very trivial question but how do I get the corresponding `MBean` from the `SinkTask` Object.